# Customizing wmv player in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007, media-player, wmv

I am pretty sure that this cannot be done but I need some confirmation.

We haveto customize a wmv player which will be added to a sharepoint page as a web part. The customization includes chnaging the skni of the player, like teh start, stop, play, volume and full screen buttons. Since the wmv player renders an object tag in HTML we won't be able to change the look of the player.

We cannot use flash or silverlight because that is not supported by our enterprise client.

Is there a way to change the look of the player?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the Player object to control the media
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd564034%28VS.85%29.aspx